# SSH Shell not popping even though the debug log shows it connected

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I try to log in to my server using the standard ssh user@host command, and although it technically connects, I'm unable to get a shell. I have used this server for months and I don't understand what's happening. I am connecting to the server through Wireguard (I do not have physical or KVM access to it) and I can ping the internal IP however, the internal site (running behind nginx) doesn't show up and SSH doesn't work either.

```
❯ ssh admin@10.0.0.1 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.1 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.1 [10.0.0.1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
```

Thanks for any help. The server OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

UPDATE:

I tried seeing what would happen if I connect to SSH through telnet and I got this message:

```
Trying 10.0.0.1...
Connected to 10.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Exceeded MaxStartups
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any idea what MaxStartups might be?